# Java Palindrome always returns true

Tags: for-loop, palindrome

I tried to create a palindrome java program with JOptionPane by using for loop, but it ends up returning true all the time no matter the input is really a palindrome or not. Can guys please help if you guys know what's wrong with the code below, thanks.

```
    public class program {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to The Palindrome!", "Hello", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");
    int len = str.length();
    int j = len - 1;
    int i = 0;
    boolean result;
    for(i = 0; i <= (len - 1)/2; i++);
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) 
            result = false;       
        j--;
    }
    if(result = true)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str + " is a palindrome.", "ByeBye", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    if(result = false)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str + " is not a palindrome.", "ByeBye", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using traditional way to check palindrome, just use the smart way. Here you go

```
boolean result = str.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you check for the value of `result`, you are using `=`, which assigns that value to the `result` variable, and always evaluates to true.

To correct your code, you can either remove the equal sign, or use `result == true` (usually you use the former, as it is more concise).

However, this may result in an error, as you are not initialising the value of result. I recommend setting it's value to `true` as the default value.